# Why isn't my form deleting multiple entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

so I have an `Array` that is filled with a bunch of repeats like `['hey','hey','yeh']` and I have a html form that removes any entry from my Array if the submitted text matches it. However, my JS/jQuery doesn't seem to be functioning the way I like. Only the first few entries seem to delete every time I press the button, as opposed to all the matches (which is what I want). Shouldn't my "each" function be going through all the items in my array and deleting all of the entries that match whatever was submitted?

HTML:

```
<form id="remove_user" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="user_num">Remove user:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user_num" name="user_num" placeholder="number">
        <input type="submit" value="(-) remove">
    </form><!-- #remove_user -->

    <ul id="user_list"></ul><!-- #user_list -->
```

JS updated with a change, but still doesn't work:

```
$('#remove_user').submit(function(){
    id = $('#user_num').val();
    $.each(myArr, function(i, value){
        if (value == id){
            myArr.splice(i, 1);
        };
    });
    $('#user_list').html('');
    for (var i=0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) {
        $('#user_list').append('<li>' +myArr[i]+ '</li>');
    };
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey i think this should be like this.

```
$.each(myArr, function(i, value){
    if (value == id){
        // delete myArr[myArr.indexOf(value)];
        myArr.splice(i, 1); //i is current index
```

};

**EDIT**

```
$('#remove_user').submit(function() {
id = $('#user_num').val();
$.each(myArr, function(i, value) {
    if (value == id) {
        myArr.splice(i, 1, '');
    };
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8M4r/)

Comment: ashirvad: nice!! it solved my issue, and makes complete sense. thanks!!

Comment: I broke it again... If I have 4 `['yeh','yeh','yeh','yeh']` and type "yeh" in the form it only deletes two of them. same goes for if I have `['yeh','yeh']` it only removes one.

Comment: Nice catch. What actually happening here is after splice the value is getting removed from the myArray but the length of myArray is same .So the value for the last two index is coming undefined. To solve this we need to maintain the index too.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part:

```
$.each(myArr, function(i, value){
        if (value == id){
            // delete myArr[myArr.indexOf(value)];
            myArr.splice(myArr.indexOf(value), 1);
};
```

with this one which uses [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
myArr = $.grep(myArr, function(value) {
  return value != id;
});
```

There's also a more beautiful way of doing this using [`.splice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) and [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/):

```
var myArr = ['le', 'le', 'la']
var removeItem = 'la';

myArr.splice($.inArray(removeItem, myArr), 1);

// Will print only 'le', 'le'
alert(myArr);
```

Here's a jsFiddle for you to try: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/4zENw/2/

Comment: thanks Leniel. My instructor also recommended "grep". But can you explain what exactly grep does?? And does `return value != id;` like an if statement like `if (value != id) { return value };?

Comment: You can learn more about grep here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/. This part: `return value != id;` is like an if statement. You're correct.

Comment: Yeh I looked it up. Thanks. But after doing "grep" how would I access only the "grepped" values? Does my array now only have those values? Because later on I do print all the values in my array     for (var i=0; i < myArr.length; i += 1) {
        $('#user_list').append('<li>' +myArr[i]+ '</li>');
        };

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .each function iterates over arrays using an integer, starting at 0, to index into them. When you take something out of the array while this is happening, jQuery's index var doesn't get told about it and you end up skipping an item.

If you iterate from the other end of the array, this isn't a problem;

```
var i = myArr.length;
while (i--) {
    if (myArr[i] === value) {
        myArr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```